# unity chrome windows "unresponsive" greyed out and can't move

Tags: 14.04, unity, google-chrome, chromium

Periodically (a few times a week, sometimes a few times a day) my entire set of chrome windows gets greyed out.  (Not just multiple tabs, but all separate windows on all workspaces including chrome apps/extensions like Hangouts).

I can't click on anything, can't move the window, can't even click the close/minimize buttons.  I can press ALT+F4 and this presents a dialog asking me to wait or force quit.

Any tips on debugging this?  Existing bug reports (it's sort of hard to search for since it's fairly generic)?  Settings to change?  Is there a way to change how unity treats "unresponsive" applications?  Is there a log for unity?

This has been happening for months and still, I'd be hard pressed to reproduce it on demand.  I'd say it's more likely to happen when it's idle but not certain of that.

**Evidence? that it's not chrome (on it's own)**

This doesn't seem to be chrome crashing, but instead unity thinking it crashed and marking it unresponsive.

Chrome itself is still running (evidence being the chrome tab with hangouts still works -- as far as audio in/out goes).

I've tried 3 different versions of chrome: chrome-stable (39), chrome-beta (40), chromium (38) and all exhibit this.  No other application exhibits this.

I've also run it with zero extensions, etc.